# How to change the config file for Riak TS when using Docker

Tags: docker-compose, riak, riak-ts

I want to run a local cluster using [the docker-compose files](https://hub.docker.com/r/basho/riak-ts/) from Basho on docker hub. However I need to change the quanta span configuration variable (usually in /etc/riak/riak.conf) called riak_kv.query.timeseries.max_quanta_span. This is usally set to =5 in riak.conf. How can I set this to a larger number across the coordinator and cluster Docker nodes (the above docker-compose.yml creates one coordinator and then the web page suggests starting 4 members, for a 5-node single-machine cluster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following blog post on running Riak in Docker:

http://basho.com/posts/technical/running-riak-in-docker/

Under the advanced configuration section it gives you four different options for how to customize your configuration.